# How to make JavaScript talk with Python through local http connection?

Tags: javascript, python, json, sockets

I am writing a script that sends some data from app A to app B in form of coded json through a local HTTP connection using sockets, etc.

app A uses python, however in app B you can only use pure JavaScript to perform operations that you justed passed with json data.

And here I have some problem, how can I send back data using pure JS that would be executed from inside app B? Also it would use port and socket, that I am already using? I am not very familiar with JS so any hints are very appriciated. Also I am not very sure that it's possible due to some security issues from this idea however maybe I am not aware of something.

---

app A python script pseudocode:

```
class Connect:
    def __init__(self, port=1, host='localhost'):
        self._host = host
        self._port = port

    # Execute a HTTP POST request to the app server and send/receive JSON data
    def json_post_request(self, route, body):
        connection = http.HTTPConnection(self._host, self._port, timeout=3000)
        connection.request('POST', route, body, head)
        response = connection.getresponse()

        data = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
        connection.close()

    # Execute a JavaScript script
    def execute_script(self, script):
        return self.json_post_request(route, ('{"js":"' + script.decode('utf-8') + '"}').encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`httplib` is not a websocket :)

maybe you need to use package `websockets`

Or try a framework for that like [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of communication you want to happen between your two apps. Do you need full duplex communication? Then I would advise using [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket). You could run the server in either your JS or in Python. You could use [Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/), which has both clients / servers available in Python and JS.

If you need communication in a specific direction, you can use a RESTful API (HTTP Request / Response). In this case, the sender of messages should be the client, whereas the receiver should be hosting the REST service. In a sense there is also a form of bidirectional communication here, but your Host is not able to initiate communication and can only respond to requests.